# The image moves out of the frame even if I did set the limits with ifs in actionPerformed -Java

Tags: java, image

The problem is that the image moves move than it should even if I added the limits. I tried the code using a rectangle and it worked properly but it doesn't when I add an image. Any ideas why and advice on how to fix that?

The main class:

```
    public class Game1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 0, y = 0, xMove =0, yMove =0;

    Image image;
    private Player player1 = new Player();
    public Game1() 
    {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(x < 0)
        {
                xMove = 0;
                x = 0;

        }

        if(x > 900)
        {
                xMove = 0;
                x = 900;
        }

        if(y < 0)
        {
                yMove = 0;
                y = 0;
        }

        if(y > 680)
        {
                yMove = 0;
                y = 680;    
        }
        x = x + xMove;
        y = y + yMove;
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                player1.moveD();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                player1.moveU();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                player1.moveL();

        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                player1.moveR();

        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            xMove=0;
            yMove=0;
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  
        super.paintComponent(g);
         player1.paint(g); 

         repaint();

} 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("PowerBall");
Game1 s = new Game1();
f.add(s);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setSize(1200,750);
f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);          
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
}
```

Player Class:

```
class Player extends JFrame{
Image image;
private int xMove = 0;
private int yMove = 0;

public Player()
{
    image = getToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Ioana\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\game1\\pic\\p1.png");

}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(image,xMove,yMove,this);
}
public void moveL()
{
    xMove= xMove - 5;
}
public void moveR()
{
    xMove = xMove + 5;

}
public void moveU()
{
    yMove = yMove - 5;
}
public void moveD()
{
    yMove = yMove + 5;
}
```

Comment: The dimensions of the image are 87x88.

Answer (score 1):

You're limiting the `xMove`/`yMove`/`x`/`y` values of the `Game1` class, but you're using the `xMove`/`yMove` values of the `Player` class to draw the image.

I would guess that you should refactor your code to remove one of those sets of variables, since it doesn't look like you need both.

You can test this theory by adding print statements any time you change any of those variables. Are they really changing when you think they are? Are you really limiting them when you think you are?